# Insert value into structure to test without modify the structure

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a data structure which is a list of lists, doesn't really matter.

```
(setf var1 create_data_Structure)
```

Now I need to insert a value inside the data structure to test something without var1 being modified.

```
(defun testsomething(data_str val)
        (let ((data_str_aux data_str))
            (progn (insert val data_str_aux)
                   (testData data_str_aux))))
```

Ok, doesn't really matter what I do with the rest of the function, but now if I write this:

```
>var1
```

It appears my my data structure with the value inside, but I didn't want to.
I tried also this:

```
(defun testsomething(data_str val)
        (let ((data_str_aux))
            (progn (setq data_str_aux data_str)
                   (insert val data_str_aux)
                   (testData data_str_aux))))
```

And it stills modifies my global structure. What would you do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: If the structure is actually a list of lists, then you *might* be able to use **copy-tree**, but that might perform more copying than you want.  You really need a copying function that's specialized to your structure.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `aux` is just an extra reference to the same object in memory, so modifying it with `insert` modifies the same object.

What you need is something like

```
(defun test-something (data-str val)
  (let ((aux (copy-my-structure data-str)))
    (insert val aux)
    (test-data aux)))
```

E.g.,

```
(defparameter var1 (list 1 2 3 4))
(defun copy-my-structure (str)
  (copy-list str))
(defun insert (val str)         ; assumes non-NIL str
  (nconc str (list val)))
(defun test-data (data)
  (list (every #'numberp data)
        (length data)))
(test-something var1 7)
==> (T 5)
var1
==> (1 2 3 4)
```